# Implementing simple business model in Haskell

Tags: haskell, data-modeling

Supose we have a very simple model:

`Station` has at least one `Train`
`Train` has at least two `Station`s

The model has to allow to check what stations any given train visits and to check what trains visit a particular station.

How to model it in Haskell?

I am a Haskell newbie, so please correct me: once an object is created, you cannot modify it - you can only make a new object based on that one (~immutability). Am I right? If so, 
I'll have to create a lot of temporary variables with semi-initialized objects (during deserialization or even in unit tests).

Basically what I need is an example of modeling domain classes in Haskell - after reading "Learn you a haskell.." I still have no idea how to use this language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a naive approach:

```
data Station = Station Train [Train]
data Train = Train Station Station [Station]
```

You should never have to create an uninitialized object. For example, here's a couple sample values:

```
grandCentral = Station regional [national]
bestWestern  = Station regional [national]
regional = Train grandCentral bestWestern []
national = Train grandCentral bestWestern []
```

However, there's a lot of drawbacks to this approach; observing the in-heap cycles is impossible from within the pure subset of Haskell, so updating or using these pieces of data is tricky. The usual workaround is to model your pointers explicitly.

```
type TrainMap   = Map TrainId Train
type StationMap = Map StationId Station
type TrainId    = Int -- use newtype for more compiler checks at
type StationId  = Int -- the cost of more programmer annoyance
data Train   = Train StationId StationId [StationId]
data Station = Station TrainId [TrainId]
```

Comment: For `Station` you could use `Station (NonEmpty TrainId)`, but unfortunately that doesn't help for trains.

Comment: @Daniel - thank you for your answer. Some questions regarding your code: firstly, can you make forward-declarations **to objects** in Haskell? secondly, when you write `regional = Train grandCentral` - is `grandCentral` a **reference**, **pointer** or **copy** of the object? Well, as I said - I am a Haskell newcomer, but if there is no proper way to model real-world logic/relations then how are we supposed to use this language? I like the idea with the map though.

Comment: @elmes There are no forward or backward declarations. There are just declarations. When you write `regional = Train grandCentral`, the GHC implementation produces a thunk which, when evaluated, produces the `Train` tag and a pointer to the `grandCentral` thunk in whatever state of evaluation `grandCentral` happens to be at the time. I'm not sure I understand the hypothesis of your final question, namely, that there is no proper way to model real-world logic/relations; can you say what you want more precisely and in what sense that is not attainable?

Comment: @elmes: You try to transfer your knowledge about OOP and it's implementation in imperative programming languages to Haskell. Just don't do that and forget all you know about it instead.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, you are right :-) I perhaps need some more examples of how to write in Haskell.. I like many aspects of this language (syntax isnt one). I need a good CRUD example in Haskell, with some back-end logic (i.e. during the create-phase).

Comment: @DanielWagner I try to use your snippet (middle one) in a `main = do...` block - ghci complains about the variable names not being in scope.. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @elmes "I try to use your snippet in a `do` block. What did I do wrong?" <- you tried to use the snippet in a `do` block. =) They're top-level declarations, no blocks needed. If you're still having trouble after this hint, it's probably best to open a new question with the exact file you wrote and the exact error message you got.